# PowerPivot table in excel is not refreshing automatically Is there any VBA code for it. I don't know much about VBA

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have a Excel file the data in it is imported to powerpivot the issue here is that each time I download the file onto a new machine from the same server where the file is stored. It shows an error and the data is not automatically refreshed. Is there any VBA code that we can use to automatically update the power pivot table. The machine has Excel 2013. After manually refreshing the file it works fine. But I have to it each time I download the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

To interact with a power pivot model though VBA you would use the `ThisWorkbook.Model` object.

So for example to Initialize the power pivot model to memory and then refresh it, it would be the following two commands.

```
ThisWorkbook.Model.Initialize
ThisWorkbook.Model.Refresh
```